# Set event.target to null

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to nullify the event.target for garbage collection as the moveclip is no longer needed. What I have roughly is this:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destroy);

 public function destroy(event:MouseEvent):void {


       event.target.parent.removeChild(event.target); 

       event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destroyShape);

       event.target = null; //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE


   }
```

I'm sure this is relatively simple but I'm not sure how to do it.

thanks

Comment: There's no need to nullify a property of an event. Even if you could it would achieve nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change MouseEvent.target value. It's a read only property. If your MovieClip doesn't exist (removeChild) and you removed event handler
`mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destroy);`
then the garbage collector automatically will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve (if it was even possible) would achieve nothing in term of Garbage Collection.

Unless redispatched the event will be garbage collected as soon as the method is done running. All properties of the event will also be discarded. This garbage collection of the event itself and its properties will have absolutely NO EFFECT on the object they point to in term of Garbage collection.

In the scope at which the event was dispatched in the first place the object will continue to exist after the event itself has been discarded. That is at that scope that the object reference must be nullified, not at the event listener scope where it will have no effect since the object still exists at the dispatching scope.

The solution accepted also does nothing. It is as relevant as applying a bandage to a wooden leg. Any local variable in function/method qualify for GC immediately after the method runs. Nullifying those variables has no effect whatsoever and does not constitute a valid answer to any problem and certainly not a GC problem. That those variables are GC does also not constitute a guaranty that the object they point to will be GC.

This is a case where a question about an inexistent and misunderstood problem is asked and answered by posting a false and irrelevant solution.

Case in point: Only a DisplayObject currently in a display list and attached to the stage has the ability to be the target of a MouseEvent. It is simply impossible for that object to become available for garbage collection before it is removed from the display list it belongs to. For those reasons that object cannot qualify for GC at the time the MouseEvent listener runs since that object still has at least one strong reference because it is attached to a display list. This is the proof that what the PO asks is misguided and any code examples are misguided as well since they cannot qualify the object for GC at that point in time.

Answer (score -1):

As @subdan states, the target property of any Event is a readonly property.
You can still null your movie clip but not like in your sample.

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destroy);

public function destroy(event:MouseEvent):void 
{

   var myMC:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;

   if( myMC )
   {  
       myMC.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, destroyShape);
       myMC.parent.removeChild(myMC);
       myMC = null; //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
   }
}
```

Comment: It's given as the right answer but only because the PO doesn't know better. Your answer is useless and achieve nothing. Any local variable is GC after the method runs. Your myMC will qualify for GC whether you nullify it or not. Voted down as it is not a valid answer to anything.

Comment: Be sarcastic as you like but at least try to defend your answer. The right answer is, what the PO asks is irrelevant and only shows his misunderstanding of GC machine. The target property of the event will be discarded correctly regardless of any action so nullify it is irrelevant even if it was possible. Your answer is also irrelevant in regard of GC machine. The myMC WILL be GC since it's a local variable, nullifying it has no effect whatsoever. The GC behavior of the object it points to will be unaffected. Finally the PO accept your answer even though it does nothing in regard to GC.

Comment: First of all I think you lack basic programming skills. 1. myMC is not a local variable but a local pointer to a global variable. 2. Objects with events listeners hanging will not be "discarded " at all. You need to remove listeners and yes: making an object null is obsolate, but if you would have at least a little experience with other programming languages you would already know that null-ing is not only a "good practice" but necessary in some cases... but what do I know ??? ...so excuse us Master! and please save us from your unfounded comments.

Comment: So many wrong statements here. In AS3: pointer do not exist period. myMC is a local variable. variables do not point to variable ever, they point to objects. local pointer do not exist. global variable are a different thing (static variable). etc ... I could go on and on. I won't comment on your programming skills but simply on your lack of AS3 knowledge. As for me my Master C.S. speaks for itself.

Comment: WOW.... are you sure you passed your Master ? it does not look like. For sure there are "pointers" is AS3, but you may have learned them as "references". Anyway... confusing static variable with global variable... closes the topic. I will stop responding to your comments since this is not a constructive discussion and for sure as longs as you do not want to learn, I cannot force you! Have a good life master!  PS: I have a master in CS as well,  and I do not mean CounterStrike! ...maybe like you!